# HDD adapter with USB

Tags: usb, hard-disk, drive-enclosure

I've been contemplating purchasing an HDD adapter. However, they all seem to be ~$20 which is too much for me.

### Requirements

- Price must be < $15 (Including shipping, not taxes).
- Must support USB 3.0
- Must support SATA2 and backward compatible w/ SATA3
- Must be 3.5 inch
- Must be available in the USA.

### Preferences

- Support for SATA3
- Support for USB 3.1
- Support for thunderbolt
- Multiple drive bays
- Support for 2.5 inch drives as well as 3.5 inch
- An enclosure instead of just an adapter.

I haven't been able to find anything at this price range.

Comment: If you're that price-sensitive, you need to tell us where you're going to purchase it. Shipping and taxes will make the difference. Do you actually need an enclosure or just an adapter?

Comment: @Gilles Must be available in the USA.